# How to create subpages for taxonomy term page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have created a custom taxonomy and what the term page will look like.

domain.com/taxonomy/term

But for each taxonomy term, I have included various custom fields and included content. The content is large and I want to display them in subpages with individual link clicks. I want to display them in subpages.

For eg:

domain.com/taxonomy/term/meta-data-1

domain.com/taxonomy/term/meta-data-2

How can I create this?

I am using Genesis Framework

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have some knowledge in php and Wordpress theming.

You could create/add a `custom-subterm` then create a specific `template` for that `custom-subterm` called `taxonomy-custom-subterm.php`.
Inside you could display all relevant informations/metadata to the `custom-term`.

If your `custom-taxonomy` is set to `hierachical` (which is the default behaviour I believe), then the url should be `/custom-taxonomy/custom-term/custom-subterm/`.

---

### Graphical representation

```
domain.com/
  L custom-taxonomy/
    L custom-term/ (using taxonomy.php OR taxonomy-custom-term.php as template)
      L custom-subterm/ (using taxonomy-custom-subterm.php as template)
```

This is based around the default Wordpress hierarchy.
Learn more @ https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/.
And @ https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png

Comment: Thank you so much @amarinediary for answering my question. Unfortunately, creating a subterm will make the situation really difficult in my case. My subterms are the same for each term.

If I have to create 2000 terms and the same 5 subterms for each term. That will total to 10,000 terms under a taxonomy. 

Is there any other alternate solution.?

Comment: Maybe creating a post/page under your `custom-term` with a custom template? And display all metas on it? post/page template would be universal. As it's a post/page, you could retrieve the `custom-term` from it.  The url should match what you want to.

Comment: OR same solution but with using `shortcodes` do display all metas on the post...

Comment: Thanks @amarinediary. I will try it out.